# messed up bootloader while dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 18.04, uefi, windows-10

I tried to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. Windows 10 was already installed and I made a separate partition and tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 on it.

The installation was successful but now I have messed up with the bootloader. It says no bootable media found. I can neither boot into windows 10 nor into Ubuntu.

Accessing the driving through the Ubuntu live CD. I have found that windows and ubuntu files are in their respective drives. So it is actually only the issue of the bootloader.

Checking the BIOS/UEFI setup, I have found that boot options only point to Ubuntu but don't even boot into that.

So how can fix this issue? Will I have to reinstall the bootloader for Windows?

Comment: Do you see your data in live CD? Copy them. You can restore Grub in Try Ubuntu or from Windows or in its flash drive.

Comment: If as you say you've managed to mangle the boot loader you can simply reinstall grub..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is very common.  Perhaps you can follow the instructions for boot-repair at this website 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Then you will have a huge list of grub choices.. You can remove them the easy way by installing grub customizer  (google how to install it).

Comment: this worked and I am now able to boot into ubuntu but i still cant boot into windows. and I cant find an option for that as well. what should I do ? Aslo when reinstalling bootloader, boot repair gave options of 3 drives to insall bootloader on. one was USB drive, one was my 1TB harddrive. Another was shown around 100 GB I did not know what that was. so I selected only one option that was 1TB hard drive. Should I have selected 2 drives ?

Comment: If boot repair cannot find windows , you may have not done a proper dual boot installation.  Check to see if the drive for windows is still there in gparted. If you use a live USB, it is included.  Or install gparted to your Ubuntu system.  If windows partition is still there, you can download a free version of windows (from Microsoft website assuming you are legal).  The make a USB disk for that iso.  Then boot and do the repair.  You might lose grub but gain back windows.  Then do boot repair one more tme.  Then you should get both listed in grub.

Comment: i had an idea just like that then i thought i should explore the options. i am not able to boot in windows by creating a custom menu entry in the bootloader and pointing the windows boot files present in different partition. actually ubuntu was not properly installed so i will have to do that again

Comment: That won't work.  you need to download and make the disk as I said.  You do need to see if the partition is still there with the usb ubuntu live boot.  If so you can recover with the windows repair usb.  If you partition does not exist, you pretty much lost all of your data.  Always make a backup.  If you still want to have a dual boot.  install windows or (repair) and then start again with ubuntu.. and remember to be mindful.